# How can I get row and column of an element in a grid of divs

Tags: javascript

I am looking for some way to get row and column of an element in the grid. I have the individual cell element itself and I want to find its row and column. The grid is formed of rows of divs and rows of divs contain divs itself. Refer the below code:

```js
var gridCols = 60, gridRows = 20;
var startRow = 10, startCol = 20, stopRow = 10, stopCol = 40;


function getCell(row, col)
{
 return document.querySelector(".row:nth-child("+(row+1)+") .gridsquare:nth-child("+(col+1)+")");
}

function genDivs(rows, cols)
{ 
 var e = document.getElementById("gridContainer");
 for(var r = 0; r < rows; r++)
 { 
  var row = document.createElement("div"); 
  row.className = "row";
  for(var c = 0; c < cols; c++)
  { 
   var cell = document.createElement("div"); 
   cell.className = "gridsquare"; 

   if(r == startRow && c == startCol)
    cell.classList.add("start");
   
   else if(r == stopRow && c == stopCol)
    cell.classList.add("stop");
   
      
      row.appendChild(cell); 
  } 
  e.appendChild(row); 
 }
}

var e = getCell(10, 10);
// Now say I don't know row and column of cell e, how can I find it out?
genDivs(gridRows, gridCols);
```

```html
 <html>
  <body>
    <div id="gridContainer"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding, save the row and column number:

```
cell.dataset.row = r;
cell.dataset.col = c;
```

If you have the cell, retrieve the parameters like this:

```
r = cell.dataset.row;
c = cell.dataset.col;
```

To access the cell you can use `querySelector`:

```
document.querySelector(`[data-row='${row}'][data-col='${col}']`);
```

```js
var gridCols = 60,
  gridRows = 20;
var startRow = 10,
  startCol = 20,
  stopRow = 10,
  stopCol = 40;

function getCell(row, col) {
  return document.querySelector(`[data-row='${row}'][data-col='${col}']`);
}

function genDivs(rows, cols) {
  var e = document.getElementById("gridContainer");
  for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    var row = document.createElement("div");
    row.className = "row";
    for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      var cell = document.createElement("div");
      cell.dataset.row = r;
      cell.dataset.col = c;
      cell.className = "gridsquare";
      if (r == startRow && c == startCol) cell.classList.add("start");
      else if (r == stopRow && c == stopCol) cell.classList.add("stop");
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    e.appendChild(row);
  }
}

genDivs(gridRows, gridCols);
var e = getCell(10, 10);
console.log(e);
console.log(e.dataset.col + "x" + e.dataset.row);
```

```html
<div id="gridContainer"></div>
```

Comment: I don't get it, I need to select some random cell in the above grid and I wanted to know it's row and column. If I don't already know the row&column how am I supposed to save it and retrieve later?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: var cell = getCell(10, 10);
console.log(cell.dataset.row, cell.dataset.col);
I tried the above and got two undefined objects.

Comment: Updated with snippet